# CarPlay sample app crashes after starting the XCode CarPlay Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I wanted to take a closer look at the sample project from Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/integrating_carplay_with_your_navigation_app After I run it (Xcode 14 beta), I go to *I/O -> External Displays -> CarPlay* to show the CarPlay Simulator but this results in a crash:

> Thread 1: "Application does not implement CarPlay template application
> lifecycle methods in its scene delegate."

I have not changed anything in the project, started it as it is. Could it be a problem related to M1 chip / Rosetta ?

Comment: Are you using the last version of the template with other version than xCode 14 beta ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. I downloaded the project from the link mentioned above and started it using Xcode Version 14.0 beta 2. But I also have Xcode 13 on my Mac.

Comment: The problem occurs when I start the CarPlay Simulator. The project itself builds fine.

Comment: I told you this because the project changed for new iOS beta and there may be incompatibilities with previous iOS or Xcode/ simulators

Comment: I tested with xCode 13.4.1 the template. only commented UIHostingConfiguration new to iOS 16, and tun without problem on simulator iPhone 12 mini + external display CarPlay . Its on a M1 Mac

Comment: @PtitXav Yeah, but I assume you have Rosetta turned off ? Try to turn it on and then build the project and start the simulator

Comment: Ok could reproduced latching xCode under Rosetta

Comment: Do you need to use Rosetta ?

Comment: Yes, for my project I need to.